# Highlight old post on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, highlight

How to highlight old post on wordpress, I have a site that has a thumbnails of videos. What I want is to have the older videos to be gray out or to have the div style to opacity so that the main focus of the viewer is the new post. Is that possible?

Comment: please let us know your findings for the old post. As per you old posts are the posts published before a specific date or it depends on your total number of posts...kindly share your code snippet as it is required to know which loop you are using to fetch the thumbnails of videos.

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

Test for posts that are so many days old date (in this case 46 days)

```
<?php
$mylimit=46 * 86400; //days * seconds per day
//$post_age = date('U') - get_post_time('U');
$post_age = date('U') - mysql2date('U', $post->post_date_gmt);
if ($post_age < $mylimit) {
echo 'this post is within my date limit ';
}
?>
```

Also you can use plugins like [Old Post Notifier](https://wordpress.org/plugins/old-post-notifier/) or [Old Posts Highlighter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/old-posts-highlighter/).